# UNION table query wrong data

Tags: php, mysql, union

I'm new mySQL user using the UNION command to add 2 query tables.  The union works except the results repeat themselves if they have the same ID.  If I delete or change the ID thru phpMyAdmin you see the entry. Example:'

```
My day | today | 12:00
My day | today | 12:00
```

and change of the ID:

```
OK day | other | 12:01
My day | today | 12:00
```

And the PHP code

```
$query = "SELECT id,title,day,time 
          FROM $db_1 
          UNION 
          SELECT id,title,day,time 
          FROM $db_2 
          WHERE month='$month' AND year='$year' ORDER BY time" ;enter code here
$query_result = mysql_query ($query);
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($query_result))

{
$day = $info['day'];
$event_id = $info['id'];
$events[$day][] = $info['id'];
$event_info[$event_id]['0'] = substr($info['title'], 0, 8);;
$event_info[$event_id]['1'] = $info['time'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick for you:

```
select distinct *
from
(
    SELECT 
        id,
        title,
        day,
        time 
    FROM 
        $db_1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        id,
        title,
        day,
        time 
    FROM 
        $db_2 
    WHERE 
        month='$month' 
        AND year='$year' 
)
ORDER BY time
```

Although group by can be used, it is less efficient. I ran into trouble with the query below and ended up running some stats as the first was returning in around 10 seconds, the second query in under half a second.

The difference is that using a group by will introduce a filesort on the subquery, which in my case caused all the problems:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN select
    ->  a.mCode as cCode,
    ->  a.mName as cName
    -> from
    ->  _user_UserStructure a
    -> where
    ->  a.pCode in
    ->  (
    ->          select
    ->                  b.pCode
    ->          from
    ->                  _user_userStructure b
    ->          where
    ->                  b.mCode='RBM1'
    ->                  and b.pCode!=b.cCode
    ->          group by
    ->                  b.pCode
    ->  )
    ->  and a.cCode != ''
    ->  and a.pCode != a.mCode
    ->  and a.mCode!='RBM1'
    -> group by
    ->  a.mCode,
    ->  a.mName
    -> order by
    ->  a.mName asc;
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+

| id | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                        |

+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+

|  1 | PRIMARY            | a     | ALL   | cCode         | NULL  | NULL    | NULL | 1769 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |

|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | b     | index | NULL          | pCode | 13      | NULL |    2 | Using where; Using filesort                  |

+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> EXPLAIN select distinct
    ->  a.mCode as cCode,
    ->  a.mName as cName
    -> from
    ->  _user_UserStructure a
    -> where
    ->  a.pCode in
    ->  (
    ->          select distinct
    ->                  b.pCode
    ->          from
    ->                  _user_userStructure b
    ->          where
    ->                  b.mCode='RBM1'
    ->                  and b.pCode!=b.cCode
    ->  )
    ->  and a.cCode != ''
    ->  and a.pCode != a.mCode
    ->  and a.mCode!='RBM1'
    -> order by
    ->  a.mName asc;
+----+--------------------+-------+----------------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+

| id | select_type        | table | type           | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                        |

+----+--------------------+-------+----------------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+

|  1 | PRIMARY            | a     | ALL            | cCode         | NULL  | NULL    | NULL | 1769 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |

|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | b     | index_subquery | pCode         | pCode | 13      | func |    2 | Using where                                  |

+----+--------------------+-------+----------------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: DISTINCT requires all the columns to be the same. You may still get duplicate IDs if some of the other columns are different in the two tables.

Comment: If you are doing a DISTINCT in the outer query, you should do a UNION ALL in the inner query.  No reason to give the optimizer even the chance of removing duplicates twice.

Comment: How is this query different than the OP's original query?

Comment: @ypercube It is different because the union is inside a subquery with a distinct placed around it to avoid any repeating data.

Comment: The OP's original query with `UNION` will remove all duplicates as well.

Comment: @ypercube Okay, wow, I have always been positive that `union` wouldn't automagically remove duplicates (and after much testing I have proved you right).

Comment: @auser I have picked through and through that query now, can you do me a favour and run the query through PHPMyAdmin or a console with the PHP variables manually entered in. The repeating issue might be outside your query.

Answer (score 0):

You could use GROUP BY

```
SELECT * from 
(SELECT id,title,day,time FROM $db_1 
 UNION 
 SELECT id,title,day,time FROM $db_2 
 WHERE month='$month' AND year='$year' ORDER BY time) m
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: On mysql distinct is much more efficient at removing duplicates. Found this out when going through the explain plan of an absurdly simple query that was taking much too long. Editing my answer to show one I just generated

Comment: @Fluffeh thank you for running and comparing the query. A very good and explained answer indeed.

Comment: Sorry I'm new, but I've tried the above lines and still not working. I get T_String error when using this: $query = SELECT id,title,day,time from(SELECT id,title,day,time FROM $db_1 UNION SELECT id,title,day,time FROM $db_2 WHERE month='$month' AND year='$year' ORDER BY time) m GROUP BY time;

Comment: I've tried all kinds of combinations of:    $query = "SELECT id,title,day,time from $db_1 UNION /UNION ALL/JOIN etc SELECT id,title,day,time FROM $db_2 WHERE month='$month' AND year='$year' ORDER BY time GROUP BY id";                                                                     {
$day = $info['day'];
$event_id = $info['id'];
$events[$day][] = $info['id'];
$event_info[$event_id]['0'] = substr($info['title'], 0, 8);;
$event_info[$event_id]['1'] = $info['time'];
}

Comment: ORDER BY time / GROUP BY id"; I produce an error, or duplicate date on the second select.  I was wondering if it was more in the second part >>>                                                                   {
$day = $info['day'];
$event_id = $info['id'];
$events[$day][] = $info['id'];
$event_info[$event_id]['0'] = substr($info['title'], 0, 8);;
$event_info[$event_id]['1'] = $info['time'];
}   or am I just not getting it?

Comment: in order to identify if the sql is ok, you could printf $query and comment out the second part first. Execute the query at the mysql itself and see if it returns correctly. If it is running fine, that means error fall on second part. If it did return error on the query, refine it.